# How to update two database if primary database unique key keeps changing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two databases, MySQL and SQL Server. I can connect to both without any problems. My problem is this MySQL Database uses id as primary key, but the SQL Server Database use Part Number as Primary Key (Accounting Software)but this changes as client change something on the desktop app.

I wanted to use a statement like this `Update * on Table WHERE id=PartNumber`,
but that will not work as Part Number will change and will not correspond to the MySQL id anymore.

P.S. I cannot change anything on accounting software's database.

P.P.S. Just to let you know I can insert into both databases but need to update both so that they are in sync so to speak

**EDITED**
MYSQL SAMPLE DATA

| ID | Type | SKU | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8104 | simple | 100196C | Pin Locating Piston APD |

MSSQL SAMPLE DATA

| strPartNumber | strDesc | strExtendedDesc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100196C | Locating Pin 100196C APD NCS Spec | Product desc |

**EDITED**
I found the solution to the problem.

I needed to use LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN in the script to make it work. Now I get the SKU to SHOW up.

```sql
SELECT
   *,
   wp_postmeta1.meta_value as SKU 
FROM
   wp_posts 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      wp_postmeta pm 
      ON (wp_posts.ID = pm.post_id 
      AND pm.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id') 
   LEFT JOIN
      wp_postmeta wp_postmeta1 
      on wp_postmeta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
      and wp_postmeta1.meta_key = '_sku' 
WHERE
   wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
```

Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I also don't understand the real issue.  You don't need a single update to run on both databases, do you?

Comment: Have you considered delete/insert (perhaps using merge) instead of update?

Comment: Your situation isn't really clear, but to make a guess: users are changing the part number in the accounting software, and thus the primary key, but *only* in sql server. You now have an app that manages/accesses/syncs both databases and you try to keep up? In that case, your problem isn't that MySQL uses ids as pk, but that the pk changes are not done at both databases, so you have to redo those yourself. Can you add triggers and a log table (to log primary key changes) to the accounting database (not the software)? Does the accounting software maybe have a log that you can access?

Comment: A field's value is expected to change over time, then it is not good as primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to keep those databases in sync.

One is to have an unchanging key in the MSSQL database just as you have a primary key in MySQL DB.
The other would be to keep a log of changes to the part number in MSSQL to be able to reconcile them with MySQL database.

There are also a third and fourth way. Either explain to the users they can't change part number because it blows up everything or... find a new job. From technology point of view there is no other way to keep those DBs in sync.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have been looking for some guidance and yours are the most helpful of all. I have been working on this for weeks now, and option 4 was looking like a good option for me. I just cannot believe that an international accounting software company is not adding ID as primary key, then again they have developers in and out of the company almost on a monthly basis so no one is taking charge of the problem, they just keep passing it on the new guys at the company. I do not work for them but for a client of them and that is where I started noticing the problems in the database.